# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:251 (message): Failed to determine the source files for the regular expression backend

Tags: c++, cmake

The project I am trying to build from source using `cmake`
is written mainly on C/C++ and Python.

The link to its source code: https://github.com/rapidsai/cuml

After successful run of comman in "cpp" subfolder with:

```
$ cmake .
```

I launched "make" there and got the error message:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:251 (message):
  Failed to determine the source files for the regular expression backend
```

Comment: Your cmake version might be too old, or too new

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov `CMakeLists.txt` of the project has this entry: `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14...3.17 FATAL_ERROR)` so error reported would be different if you were right.

Comment: I would try this: https://github.com/google/benchmark/issues/351#issuecomment-285991773 `-DRUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX=0 -DRUN_HAVE_POSIX_REGEX=0`

Comment: The error is probably caused by building [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark). If it is true, then before the error message you show should be a line `-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_REGEX`. Please, show **all output** from that line till the error message. An example of output you could find in [that issue](https://github.com/google/benchmark/issues/351).

Comment: 1. Which version of cuML are you using?
2. Please can you run and then post the output of `print_env.sh`

Answer (score 5):

It's due to introduced issue in gtest/benchmark.

Adding `-DHAVE_STD_REGEX=ON -DRUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX=1` to CMake args might solve this if you use C++11 or later versions.

```
ExternalProject_Add(${name}
    GIT_REPOSITORY ${location}
    GIT_TAG HEAD
    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    ${OPENMIND_UPDATE_EXTERNAL_DEPS_CMD_PARAM}

    CMAKE_ARGS
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<INSTALL_DIR>
            -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}
            -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}
            -DGIT_EXECUTABLE=${GIT_EXECUTABLE}

            -DHAVE_STD_REGEX=ON
            -DRUN_HAVE_STD_REGEX=1
    )
```